# Using Odoo Docker image to edit default base addons

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I want to use the default Odoo Docker container but also need to modify the base addons like the employee module and pre-built modules, which I need to modify.

Is that possible? Also, I am not looking for custom-addons which I can mount and use. But I want to edit the inbuilt addons, which come with odoo.

Answer (score 0):

You should view odoo.conf to get path save addons, by default config Odoo addons in the folder:

```
[options]
addons_path = /mnt/extra-addons
```